# Zero Homogeneous Polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree n. Is it true that if $\forall x,f(x)=0$, then the coefficients of $f$ are all zero?

Comment: Isn't this true of all polynomials $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, not just the homogeneous ones?

Comment: Yes. It is true for all such polynomials.

Comment: Is there an elementary proof of that? I feel like there should be, and I'm overlooking something extremely obvious.

Comment: The coefficients of $f$ are related to its derivatives at $0$. The derivatives of the zero function are all zero.